# What impresses the fancy ladies? Do they really matter?

Tags: passpartout

Whenever I get to Act 2 I can't paint to impress anyone except the business guys and that always lands me a job at a design company. Of course, there are certain types of paintings that certain types of people like. So what are the snobby ladies impressed by (more realism, more complexity, etc.) and does selling more paintings to them get me a different path in the story?

Comment: On behalf of men everywhere, +1 for title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of details. Just details. What I do is paint the background one color, like Red, then use the pen tool to draw lots of lines in similar colors, like oranges and yellow. I will have some long lines and lots of little lines. It takes more than a full billing period to complete one painting and it looks like expressionist art, but the AI noble ladies love it. I started out getting $400 to $500 a painting and I'm up to way more than $1,000 a painting now and I'm not even in Act III yet.